# How do I select src between <> if img exists?

Tags: regex

I need to select `src="` using a regular expression in the form: //, but only if it is within an image tag.

This should return true:
`<img alt="Alt text" src="/directory/Images/my-image.jpg" />`

This to return false:
`<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>`

The end result will be replacing the `scr="`, which the application I am using performs, I need the regex for the find.

Comment: Parsing HTML using Regex is a bad, bad..., instead use a selector, which is much safer, e.g. `document.querySelector('img[src^="/directory/Images"]')` ... or `querySelectorAll()` to get a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the standard disclaimer: *if you are using regexes to parse a HTML DOM, you are **DOING IT WRONG***. With all structured data (XML, JSON, and so forth), the right way to parse HTML is to use something built for that purpose, and query it using its querying system.

That said, it is often the case that what you want is a quick hack on the commandline or the search field of an editor or whatever, and you don't want or need to faff with writing an application that loads in DOM-parsing libraries.

In that case, if you're not actually writing a program, and you don't mind that there are edge-cases where any regex you try will break, then consider something like this:

`/<img\b[^<>]+\bsrc\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/i` ... maybe replacing the leading `/` and trailing `/i` with whatever other thing your language uses to denote a case-insensitive regular expression.

Note that this makes assumptions, that the url is quoted with doublequotes, the tag is correctly formed, there are no extraneous `<img` strings in the document, there are no doublequotes in the URL, and countless others that I didn't think of, but a proper parser would. These assumptions are a large part of why using a parser is so important: it makes no such assumptions, and if fed garbage, will correctly let you know that you did so, rather than trying to digest it and giving you pain later on.

- `<img\b` - an img tag. The word boundary ensures this isn't an imgur tag or whatever.
- `[^<>]+` - one or more characters, with no closing tag, and for safety, no opening tags either.
- `\bsrc\s*=\s*` - 'src=', but with optional whitespace, and another word-boundary check.
- `"([^"]+)"` - some URL consisting of non-quote characters, within quotes.

Now, be aware that since we're doing NO security checking on the URL, you could be grabbing anything, such as `javascript:...something malicious...`, or it could be 6GB long - you just don't know. You could add in checking for such things, but you'll always miss something, unless you control the input and know exactly what you're parsing.

Your mention of "my application" does mean that I must reiterate: the above is almost certainly the ***wrong way*** to do it if you are writing an application, and the question you *should* be asking is probably closer to "how do I get the value of the src attribute of an img tag from a HTML page, in my chosen programming language?" rather than "how do I use regexes to extract this token from this HTML tag?"

When I say this, I don't mean "ivory-tower computer scientists will look down their nose at you" - though I admit there can be a lot of that kind of snootiness in programming :D

I mean something more like... "you're setting yourself up for pain as you run into edge-case after edge-case, and spiral down into a deep rabbit-hole of infinitely refining your regex. And you can likely avoid the pain with a simple one-liner, infinitely nicer than regex, perhaps `document.querySelector('img[src^="/directory/Images"]')` as @LGSon suggests in a comment.

People will say this because they've *had* this pain, and they're wincing at the idea that you might suffer it too.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me what I needed. 

To clarify, the application I am using, not writing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to match that. [This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/rbvM6x/1/) is just an example and it is not certainly the best expression:

```
(src=")(.+)(.jpg|.JPG|.PNG|.png|.JPEG)"
```

You can wrap your target image URLs with a capturing group `()`, maybe similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/fB1yx5/1):

```
(src=")((.+)(.jpg|.JPG|.PNG|.png|.JPEG))"
```

and simply call it using `$2` (group #2).

[image]

[image]

You can also simplify it as you wish by adding ignore flag such as [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/Gr8R3W/1/):

```
src="((.+)(\.[a-rt-z]+))"
```

[image]

[image]